# How to Disable a textfield in Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, textfield, appcelerator-titanium

It's as simple as it looks
How to disable text field from user input or even displaying soft keyboard
I want it blurred and locked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$.textview.editable = false;
```

you can add also

```
$.textview.touchEnabled = false;
```

Comment: $.textview.editable = false; 
done good with me.Already got it after i asked the question but left so i can get better results or suggestions
thanks